# To create unicode string from ascii string in vc 6.0

Tags: visual-c++, unicode, string-conversion

Can anyone please help me knowing how to create unicode strings from ascii strings. Below I a have a piece of code which is actually not working properly. can any one suggest me what can be a better change in my code.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE *file;
    char fname[10]="abc.txt";
    wchar_t fwname[10];
    swprintf (fwname, L"%s",fname);

    file = _wfopen(fwname, L"w");

    fwprintf (file, "%c%c%c", 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF);

    fwprintf(file, L"This is my utf-8 encoded file");
    fclose(file);
    WinExec("\"C:\\Program Files\\EditPlus 3\\editplus.exe\\abc.txt", SW_SHOWNORMAL);

    return 0;
}
```

I need your suggestion for the statement

```
 swprintf (fwname, L"%s",fname);
```

Comment: Try `%S` (capital S) for format specifier. `%s` means "same width as the function" (ASCII for `printf`, Unicode for `wprintf`), while `%S` means "opposite width". You could also try `%hs` and `%ls` to explicitly request ASCII or Unicode string, correspondingly. Not sure how much of that is supported in VC6 though; it's ancient.

Comment: Dear Igor,

Thank you for your valuable reply. I got the the problem.